# How do I convert a grilling recipe to an oven/ broiling recipe?

Tags: oven, grilling

I found a recipe in a magazine that was for grilled pork butt. I live in New York City with no access to a grill. I Googled how to convert from grilling to oven/ broiling. I wound up with a very tasty burned butt.

Comment: What did you try? How did you change the recipe?

Comment: To tell you the truth it was so long ago I don't remember, it was the cooking time only I believe

Comment: I'd hate to be the person who tasted your burned butt.

Comment: Lol I am a member of Cooks Illustrated and I asked them how to convert the Rx. I was told to listen to their Radio show. I don't own a radio I have every other electrical "do-dad"but no radio so they said they would write it in the next edition of the magazine.  I have been waiting and waiting , it fan ally came and I snatched it from my husbands hand .......... No conversion. BIG SURPRISE☹️

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned a butt in your question, I'll start there. The way to get close to the crispy sear and smokey flavor you get from grilling is, surprisingly, to cook the butt at a very low temp (~200-225 F) until the internal temp. gets to about 135 F.

Before putting the roast in the oven, you want to massage a generous amount of olive oil all over the meat and season it to suit your tastes.

When the internal temp gets to ~135 F (count on 3-6 hours depending on the weight), remove the roast from the oven and tent foil over it. Heat your oven to its hottest temp (~500 F). When the oven is fully heated, uncover the butt and put it back in the oven until the internal temp reaches between 145 F (about medium) to 165 F (well done).

This method will give your meat a nice crunchy sear on the outside, while leaving it juicy and flavorful inside. The high temp at the end will also create some smoke and add to that grilled flavor.